# Angular2 - Multi-Content with downgraded ng2-component

Tags: angular

Im trying to upgrade our ng1 project to ng2 with angular-upgrade mechanism. Actually i rewrite a component, that provide multiple-content (in angular 1.5 multiple-transclusion / slots).

My question is, its possible to use multi-content in a component, that will downgrade to use it in ng1 environment.

I try this since yesterday to get it work. It works if i using one ng-content element, but if i try to use two or nore ng-content, i getting always an error that i use x ng-content but 1 slot is provided.

My Component look like

```
@Component({
selector: NgContentTest.UPGRADE_ELEMENT_NAME,
template: `
    <div>
        <div style="background-color:red ">
            <ng-content select="[con1]"></ng-content>
        </div>

        <div style="background-color: yellow; display: block;height: 55px;">
            <ng-content select="[cont2]"></ng-content>
        </div>
    </div>
`
})
export class NgContentTest {
    static UPGRADE_ELEMENT_NAME = 'ngContentTest';
}
```

Consumer is a ng1 directive with following template example:

```
<ng-content-test> 
        <div cont1>
           Content - 1 
        </div>
        <div cont2>
            Content - 2
        </div>
</ng-content-test>
```

Error:
**The component NgContentTest has 2  elements, but only 1 slots were provided.**

Comment: I have the same problem on my side. See this plunkr: https://plnkr.co/edit/E2bu6gRwAO4xXbYlC56q?p=info. Looks like a bug?!

Comment: Could it be that `<ng-content select="[con1]">` should be `<ng-content select="[cont1]">`?

Comment: its only type in this example, on my implementation i using different selectors.

Answer (score 1):

This is fixed with Angular 4.0.0: https://github.com/angular/angular/pull/12675

I posted a [plunkr](http://plnkr.co/edit/6SFy7nbK6TgtfQ44tMfs?p=preview) at the bottom there which highlights the issue.

[SO requires some code](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262126/why-must-jsfiddle-net-links-be-accompanied-by-code-while-there-are-no-restrictio) in order to link directly to the plunkr, and the code required to show an ng1/ng2 hybrid app wouldn't really make sense in the context of this answer, so...

```
here's some code...
```